# Python 3 integer division

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

In Python 3 vs Python 2.6, I've noticed that I can divide two integers and get a float. How do you get the Python 2.6 behaviour back?

Is there a different method to get int/int = int?

Comment: Use `//` (floor division) instead of `/` (true division).

Comment: [PEP 238](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/node7.html) introduced the `//` floor division operator.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
int_div  = a // b
```

Comment: Note that `//` is available in Python2 as well (since 2.2, I believe).

Comment: Note that `1.0 // 2` and `1 // 2.0` maybe surprisingly return a float with value `0.0`.

Comment: Floor divisions are NOT integer divisions. A floor division will return -2 for -3 / 2, while an integer division should return -1 (there's no floor or ceil in integer land).