# how do you round a decimal number to a whole number?

Tags: python-2.7

This is the code I am using but I keep getting a decimal number and I would like to get a whole number:

```
 total=0
      for i in empty:
          i=ord(i)
          total=total+i
      total=total/8
      print("this is you offset factor.....")
```

The numbers I keep on getting are numbers like this:
70.75 or 62.625

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A minimal amount of research, like searching for "python round", would have given you the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507808/python3-integer-division)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` to `int`

```
>>> int(70.75)
70
>>> int(round(70.75, 0))
71
```