# How can I; if var is integer then execute

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I am trying to create a decimal to binary converter. The user inputs their value, and the amount is divided by two each time and added to the `invertedbinary` list. The amount is then converted back into an integer, to be divided by two again and so on.

```
value = int(input("Please enter the decimal value to be converted to binary."))
    invertedbinary = []
    while value >= 1:
        value = (value/2)
        invertedbinary.append(value)
        value = int(value)
        print (invertedbinary)
    for n,i in enumerate(invertedbinary):
        if i == isinstance(invertedbinary,int):
            invertedbinary[n]=0
        else:
            invertedbinary[n]=1
    print (invertedbinary)
```

Let's say I input the number seventeen. This is the output:

```
[8.5]
[8.5, 4.0]
[8.5, 4.0, 2.0]
[8.5, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]
[8.5, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So we can tell that from the last line of ones, my `isinstance` attempt did not work. What I want to be able to do, is that if the amount is anynumber.5 then to display it as a 1, and if it is a whole number to display as a zero. So what it should look like is `[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`. Ones for each float value, and zeroes for the integers.

What can I use instead of `is instance` to achieve this?

For anyone wondering, I've called it `invertedbinary` because when printed `invertedbinary` needs to be flipped around and then printed as a string to display the correct binary value.

Comment: I changed this to [tag:python-3.x] as this requires `int / int` gives `float` behaviour; [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507808/python3-integer-division).

Comment: You don't want `i == isinstance(invertedBinary,int)` you just want `isinstance(invertedBinary,int)` I'm pretty sure...

Comment: Although, not actually in this case, because you care if the number is a whole number, not an `int` type necessarily.

Comment: Anyway, in this case you should be using the modulus operator: `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check wether the `round` value is equal to the value...

```
if (round(x) == x):
    # x is int
else:
    # x is float/double
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for that. It's now working as intended!

Comment: @AugustWilliams Sometimes, old and obvious works best ;-)

Comment: @KenY-N What's the problem with 8.49999999999999999?

Comment: I am fairly new to Python so I don't understand the example you have provided @KenY-N . However, in this specific program the floats will always be .5.

Comment: @KenY-N But that wasn't the condition. `round(8.4999999) == 8.499999` is `False`, so it won't be treated as an int value

Comment: @AugustWilliams Please [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091689/python-floating-point-number-comparison) for starters.

Comment: @YotamSalmon Ack! Too little coffee this morning. Let me delete myself being an idiot...