# Quotient Without The Decimal Point in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a Python 3.5.2 program which includes division.

When I ran the following:

```
>>> 10/2
5.0
```

Though the answer is correct, it has a decimal point. What should be done to get quotient without decimal point, for example, `10/2` should yield `5`, not `5.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507808/python3-integer-division) answer. In Python 3 Integer division is performed using the `//` operator, and the regular division operator can yield float. Check `1/2` for example - if you get `0.5`, that's not Integer division, `0` is. IDLE is irrelevant here.

Comment: If you find an answer elsewhere, please flag as duplicate rather than copying the answer across.