# Python Middle String Print

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python and I have to create a program that prints the middle character of a user-inputted string. Here is what I have:

```
#accept string from user then print middle character

x = input("Enter a string: ")
print(x[len(x)/2-1])
```

However I keep getting this error when I try to run the program:

> "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

Im not sure how to fix this or how to get this program to work. Please help!

Comment: You're on Python3? Use // for integer division, / will return a float (e.g. 4/2 = 2.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Comment: @BertRaeymaekers This is a complete answer I was just writing. You should probably bother doing that instead of leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Changing / to // helped and its now printing sort of the right answer. For example, if I enter "1234567" it prints "3" which is not the middle number. How do I fix this? - Nevermind, I figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just do //2, dont do //2-1

Comment: @JordanJackson that's a different problem in your logic. What will you do when the string has an even number of chars?

Comment: @Mitch: I don't think that this is a duplicate. It is infact the opposite problem.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Sure, this is a duplicate then: [Python 3 integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507808/python3-integer-division)

Comment: @Mitch: yes, that is a better duplicate

Answer (score 4):

From your error I infer that you are using python 3.

In python 3 division between two integers returns a float:

```
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 4/2
2.0
```

But a indeces must be integers, so you get the error. To force an integer division you must use the `//` operator:

```
>>> 3//2
1
>>> 4//2
2
```

Alternatively you can use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) or [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) if you want more control on the rounding of the floats.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
x = raw_input("Enter a string: " )
print (x[:len(x)//2])
```