# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str on recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def NumberToSymbol(r):
    nuc={0:"A", 1:"C", 2:"G",3:"T"}
    return nuc.get(r)
def NumberToPattern(index, k):
    if k == 1:
        return NumberToSymbol(index)
    prefixIndex=index/ 4
    r = index % 4
    symbol=NumberToSymbol(r)
    PrefixPattern =NumberToPattern(prefixIndex, k-1)
    return  PrefixPattern+ symbol

print(NumberToPattern(45,4))
```

And this is my output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-5a1c7e64259c> in <module>
----> 1 print(NumberToPattern(45,4))

<ipython-input-168-331109643d8f> in NumberToPattern(index, k)
      7     if k == 1:
      8         return symbol
----> 9     PrefixPattern =PrefixPattern+NumberToPattern(prefixIndex, k-1)
     10     return  PrefixPattern+ symbol

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

`r` is a key, `index` and `k` are numbers. I want to convert index(base 10) to base k, then I want change every value of number in base k, like a dictionary, finally I want to obtained a string.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you're concatenating a None ("NoneType") to str. If you look closely, `NumberToSymbol` intends to return a `str`, but when the key (`r`) doesn't exist in `nuc`, it returns `None` instead of `str`, hence the error.

The reason `r` is not found in `nuc` is that: `prefixIndex=index/ 4` can result in a floating point number `5/4 == 1.25` but you were expecting to get `1`. So, you need integer division there.

To perform integer division, replace: `prefixIndex=index/ 4` with `prefixIndex = index // 4`. Read more about [Python integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507808/python3-integer-division).